# LINQ Except does not work for custom entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this `__GlobalHeaderList` which contains two entities now i need to add more entities into this list  whose reference are different to the one already in the list lets say

```
HeaderEntity1.Reference = 'A'
HeaderEntity2.Reference = 'B'
```

now I have this `linq` query that retrieves records from database for header entities

```
string[] _References = { "A", "B", "C" };


 List<HeaderEntity> _FilteredMatchedHeader = new HeaderRepository().
                     GetHeaderEntitiesByAccountID(__GlobalAccountVariable.MasterAccount.AllChildAccounts.Select(x => x.ID)).
                     Where(x => References.Contains(x.Reference)).Except(__GlobalHeaderList).ToList();
```

that brings 3 entities

```
HeaderEntity1.Reference = A
HeaderEntity2.Reference = B                                                       
HeaderEntity3.Reference = C
```

but is not excluding the 1&2 and following code contains 5 entities instead of 3

```
__GlobalHeaderList.AddRange(_FitleredMatchedHeader);
```

the logic in `linq` query upto `select` loads all headers entities after that filtering is applied using `where clause` but `except` in the filtering is not working. can any one help please

Comment: Is there any equality mechanism in `HeaderEntity` to find out if two objects are same or not other than being two difference references?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal .no

Comment: Then you need to.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal. I cann't change the entity

Comment: read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Except works on the principal of equality. For primitive datatypes that's easy, because .Net has done the work for us.

For custom complex types (read classes), we need to implement that mechanism. One way is to override the `Equals` method. Other way is to create an `EqualityComparer` (which suits you as mentioned by you that your entity is closed for modifications).

Except method has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) which does this type of comparison. SO and internet is full of such examples.